# ProxyInfo - ¿Como añadir funcionalidad para android 4.x?

Tags: android

Esta funcion solo funciona con android 5.x en adelante.

Hay alguna otra forma para que funcione en dispositivos con SO anteriores? Gracias de antemano

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static WifiConfiguration setProxy(WifiConfiguration conf, String hostname, int port, List<String> bypass, PROXY_TYPE type) {
    try {
        //linkProperties is no longer in WifiConfiguration
        Class proxyInfoClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyInfo");
        Class[] setHttpProxyParams = new Class[1];
        setHttpProxyParams[0] = proxyInfoClass;
        Class wifiConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration");
        Method setHttpProxy = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy", setHttpProxyParams);
        setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);

        //Get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
        Class ipConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration");
        Field f = ipConfigClass.getField("proxySettings");
        Class proxySettingsClass = f.getType();

        Class[] setProxySettingsParams = new Class[1];
        setProxySettingsParams[0] = proxySettingsClass;
        Method setProxySettings = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setProxySettings", setProxySettingsParams);
        setProxySettings.setAccessible(true);


        ProxyInfo pi = null;
        String Type = null;
        switch (type) {
            case MANUAL:
                Type = "DHCP";
                pi = ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy(hostname, port, bypass);
                break;
            case PAC_URL:
                Type = "PAC";
                pi = ProxyInfo.buildPacProxy(Uri.parse(hostname));
        }

        //pass the new object to setHttpProxy
        Object[] params_SetHttpProxy = new Object[1];
        params_SetHttpProxy[0] = pi;
        setHttpProxy.invoke(conf, params_SetHttpProxy);

        //pass the enum to setProxySettings
        Object[] params_setProxySettings = new Object[1];
        params_setProxySettings[0] = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) proxySettingsClass, Type);
        setProxySettings.invoke(conf, params_setProxySettings);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conf;
}
```

Comment: que es el objeto PROXY_TYPE y como llamas este método añade un ejemplo Alex. Revisando el ejemplo generalmente el uso de "reflexion" como en este caso Class wifiConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration");
        Method setHttpProxy = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy", setHttpProxyParams);
        setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true); funciona para anteriores versiones pero no para nuevas, aquí comentas que es alreves :0

Comment: Proxy_Type es un enum no viene al caso es solo para saber si es DHCP o PAC. buildDirectProxy(hostname, port, bypass) esta linea es la razon de mi pregunta dice android studio que es de LOLLIPOP para arriba...

Comment: tengo que añadir algo mas?