# Aplicación solo funciona en modo debug

Tags: android

Me ha pasado algo raro mi aplicacion solo se ejecuta en modo debug. Lo intente de esta otra forma: Build -> Build - APK y luego la instale mismo resultado!
Cada vez que intento compilarla lo hace perfectamente bien pero me sale la pantalla que ven que puede hacer y es solo en mi terminal pues comparti la apk y funciona perfectamente bien. Ayuda

[image: Imagen del bug]

Comment: Imagino se queda en esa pantalla y no continua, revisa en las opciones de desarrollador que imagino las tienes habilitadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo he experimentado este problema, he visto que como opción puede agregar el siguiente permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Pero personalmente lo que realizo es revisar en Settings (Configuración) en la opciones de desarrollo, elimino la app que se este debuguendo.

También debo tener deshabilitada la opción "Wait for debugger" ya que esta puede provocar el problema que comentas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra solución es simplemente reinicia tu pc ya que un proceso puede estar provocando que se quede en la pantalla esperando.

Comment: me funciono lo que me dijiste de Developer Options muchas gracias x la ayuda

Comment: Un placer Alex, saludos.

Comment: me puede ayudar con esta pregunta [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166366/como-saber-el-estado-de-mi-conexion)

Comment: @AlexRivas ya respondí,saludos!

Comment: si ya lo vi mañana voy a probar lo que me diste a ver... Cualquier duda te la dejo en los comentarios. Gracias

Comment: mira a ver si me puedes ayudar con esta que la puse y nadie me hizo caso...[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/165204/proxyinfo-como-a%c3%b1adir-funcionalidad-para-android-4-x)