# ¿Como saber el estado de mi conexion?

Tags: android

He buscado y no he encontrado nada que me diga como hacer para avisar al usuario que se ha conectado a una red. Se que es algo con Broadcast Reciever pero no se que tengo que hacer. Yo hice uno que me funciona pero es para listar wifis. Diganme si este lo puedo modificar para lograr lo que quiero. Gracias x cualquier ayuda.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            showWifis();
        }
    }
};




public void detectWifi() {
    registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifiManager.startScan();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuando te conectes a cualquier red wifi se muestre un mensaje?

Comment: exacto y tambien poder hacer cosas como desenmascarar un boton, etc

Comment: Alex mira [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060552/5587982), creo que es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crea tu clase que extienda de `BroadcastReceiver` y que pueda detectar cuando te conectas a una nueva red mediante [networkInfo.isConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "WifiReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to : " + ssid);
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Network not connnected!");
        }
    }
}
```

En tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` registra el `receiver`:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".WifiReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>         
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Desde `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`, puedes registrar el receiver:

```
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
  intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
  WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
  registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, intentFilter);
```

De esta forma en el LogCat podrás observar cuando te conectas o desconectas a una Red WiFi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me funciona de maravilla pero me entra a la funcion demasiadas veces el toast que puse para decir que estas conectado se me queda ahi pues no se porque pero entra muchas veces incluso estando ya conectado alguna sugerencia??

Comment: El Broadcastreceover es un componente que registra eventos del sistema, en este caso el sistema es el que esta enviando la información acerca de que esta conectado.

Comment: ya lo arregle simplemente lo llamo desde la funcion que conecta y me sale una sola vez, necesito tu ayuda ahora. es relacionado con esto mismo [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167034/mandar-informacion-de-una-clase-a-un-activity)

Comment: @AlexRivas ok si solo quieres se llame una vez solo registra registerReceiver() y cuando no desees la información unregisterReceiver(), saludos.

Comment: gracias. me puedes ayudar con el enlace que te di?

Comment: necesito ayuda con esto [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167117/como-establecer-el-proxy-de-una-wifi-en-android-4-x)