# Mandar informacion de una clase a un activity

Tags: android

Tengo esta clase:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "WifiReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Conectado a: " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to : " + ssid);
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "Network not connnected!");
    }
}
}
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que al entrar en el if() le diga a mi activity que esconda el progressBar y muestre un boton. No se como hacerlo.
Esta es la activity

```
public class HelperConnection extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_helper_connection);

    this.setTitle("Login UCF");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bindUI();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Siga los pasos para establecer conexión con la red", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (textInputUser.getText().length() == 0)
                textInputUser.setError("Campo requerido");
            else if (textInputPassw.getText().length() == 0)
                textInputPassw.setError("Campo requerido");

            else {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.in_from_left));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.out_from_left));

                mViewFlipper.showNext();

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

                progressBar.performClick();

                if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId());
                    detectWifi();

                } else {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId());
                    detectWifi();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HelperConnection.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("runWeb", true);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void bindUI() {
    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
    mContext = this;
    btnFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.load_steps_login);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    textInputPassw = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_passw);
    textInputUser = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_user);
    loginActivity = new LoginActivity();
}

private void tryConnection() {
    loginActivity.helperConnect(wifiManager);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Espere...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

La funcion detectWifi no viene al caso.
Como puedo decirle a este activity que cuando se conecte a la wifi haga lo que pedi anteriormente? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: En pocas palabras deseas que al detectar un cambio en la conexión realice un cambio en la UI de HelperConnection

Comment: exacto,pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción mas inmediata que se me ocurre es simplemente con un Intent, pero depende de cómo esté hecha tu app. Envías otro intent desde el `WifiReceiver` a tu `Activity` de manera explícita. Para hacer esto asegúrate de que solo tienes una instancia del Activity (sino se creará otro activity encima). Me refiero concretamente a los `launchModes`

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Si por lo que fuera no puedes / quieres usar intents, entonces puedes usar un patrón como el Observer: El objetivo es que tu `activity` (o cualquier otra clase) se suscriba al `WifiManager`, y éste, a su vez, le(s) llame cuándo tenga datos nuevos:

1 - Crea en tu clase WifiReceiver un método llamado por ejemplo:
`void subscribe(WifiChangeListener listener)`
 En este método, guarda una referencia al listener en, por ejemplo, una `List`. Haz que esta lista de suscriptores sea una variable de la instancia.

2 - Implementa una interfaz llamada `WifiChangeListener` (o el nombre que quieras) con un método llamado (por ejemplo) `void onWifiChange(String ssid);`

3 - Haz que tu Activity implemente la interfaz `WifiChangeListener, (y por tanto el método onWifiChange(String ssid))

4 - Finalmente, en tu Activity, en el `OnCreate`, suscribe la clase, la llamada será algo así.
Es importante que solo crees un WifiReceiver en el Activity, así que guárdate la referencia en una variable de la instancia.

`wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
wifiReceiver.subscribe(this);`

5 - Cuando recibas el intent en el `WifiReceiver`, simplemente recorre la lista de suscriptores y para cada uno de ellos llama al `void onWifiChange(String ssid)`, si quieres pasar info entonces modifica el signature del onWifiChange a lo que necesites.

Es decir quedaría algo así:

```
  public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String TAG = "WifiReceiver";
        private final List<WifiChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
                String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                for(final WifiChangeListener listener : listeners) {
                    listener.onWifiChange(ssid);
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to : " + ssid);
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Network not connnected!");
            }
        }

        public void subscribe(@NonNull final WifiChangeListener listener) {
            listeners.add(listener)
        }
    }
```

Y tu Activity:

```
public class HelperConnection extends AppCompatActivity {
final WifiReceiver wifiReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver() //solo lo instancias aquí y te lo guardas
        .....
 }
 ...

private void tryConnection() {
    loginActivity.helperConnect(wifiManager);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Espere...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    //no instanciamos de nuevo wifiReceiver, sino que usamos la misma instancia:
    //WifiReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver(); --> BORRAR
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Comment: Pero el OP desea realizar un cambio en base a una acción en su Activity.

Comment: Su Activity recibirá la nueva información del SSID mediante el Intent o mediante el onWifiChange de manera asíncrona. En ese momento ya podrá hacer la acción que crea pertinente, en este caso ocultar el progressBar y ocultar el botón.

Comment: que quieres decir con el paso 1?

Comment: @AlexRivas te he puesto código de ejemplo

Comment: gracias, tengo una duda listeners.add(listeners)? no entiendo añado eso?? no sera listener.add(listeners)?

Comment: @AlexRivas Uy si un error al escribirlo, sería `listeners.add(listener)` (Editado en la respuesta)

Comment: @tomacco no me entra en el onWifiChange que implemente... porque pasa eso??

Comment: cuando implemento la interfaz en el activity y voy a la declaracion de esta me dice que onWifiChange is never used y lo tengo implementado

Comment: pudieras explicarme mejor el ultimo paso creo que es el que no entiendo

Comment: @AlexRivas Te he dejado el código de cómo quedaría la clase WifiManager, (no lo he compilado así que podría haber errores), pero es la idea.

Comment: eso pense... pero sigue sin entrarme al onWifiChange... ahora no me da el warnig de never used pero no entra...

Comment: @AlexRivas resumiendo el flujo es:
- Activity se suscribe a WifiReceiver.
- WifiReceiver guarda la referencia a Activity
- Cuando llegan datos a través del Intent, WifiReceiver llama a los suscriptores, es decir en este caso a tu Activity.

Comment: @AlexRivas: Cuando digo WifiManager me refiero a WifiReceiver

Comment: @AlexRivas Asegúrate de que no instancias el WifiReceiver sino *una única vez* en el OnCreate de tu Activity

Comment: habia una linea de codigo que no habia visto... me funciona perfectamente muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @AlexRivas  súper!!